# What kind of side work can math professors (researchers) do for extra income?

Tags: career-development

I am considering a career as a math professor with interests in Abstract Algebra and Topology. I wonder if there's any side work that a math professor can do for extra income?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe ask on the academia stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

Getting a job as a professor is non-trivial, and depending on the environment, you may not have the connections or time or ability to do extra work.

Some professors consult for companies depending on their needs, usually based on some application area of their expertise. But, you  need to know companies that you can provide value to.